# How to change a Shortcut for Sidebar scrolling?

Tags: interface, add-on, 2d

I found out that newest Blender version as 3.6.1 or 4.0.0 Alpha have a new hotkey for Sidebar scrolling and it is CTRL + Wheel Up/Down. Earlier is was simply Wheel Up/Down. So how to change it back? I didn't found a way to change it in Preferences -> Keymap. Maybe you know some way to easily create an addon to change or maybe I can do it through some Config in a root folder?
Thanks everyone for answers!

Comment: I use absolutely Default Settings and Default Keymaps but it is still with CTRL. It's so strange.

Comment: @Gorgious I don't know if he messed up something. In my Blender 3.6.1 I have to use Ctrl with the mouse wheel, too. It isn't like this in my 3.5 version.

Comment: @Gorgious let my clarify something. My wheel press works as well but this let you move Sidebar Up and Down. But I speak about Scrolling/switching between Tabs in Sidebar when I want to jump up to another add-on. In newest versions we need to use CTRL + Wheeling Up/Down instead of simply Wheeling Up/Down

Comment: Oh, right sorry scratch that, I see what you mean. Thank you for clarifying. I don't know if it's possible to change this shortcut though. It might be a regression from a recent commit, in which case it might be a good idea to report it to the developers

Comment: @Gorgious, I created a topic on official site, so if you want to developers fix this, you can support me and leave a comment of your thoughts on this
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/110503
I would be appreciate for that

Comment: Thank you very much. We'll see what they say about it. Cheers

Comment: Under Windows 10, it's still just the scroll wheel without Ctrl in both 3.5.1 and 3.6.1 to switch between sidebar tabs here.

Comment: Hi guys, developers answered, this is not a bug, this is re-worked features. When you switching tabs by CTRL + Wheeling and general Wheeling to Tabs stack scroll. But I realized that we can change a shortcut for Tabs Stack Scroll but now way to change shortcut for Switching Tabs.